# How to pass a data to subscriber in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, subscribe

I have a below service with subscribe "**User**".

```
 public getEmployees(): Observable<User> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/employee`;
    return this.http.get<User>(url);
  }
```

My question is How i can call getEmployees with User data. I am trying with below code but it's getting error?

```
const _user: User = {
      userId: "30294
}

 this.userAccountService.getEmployees().subscribe((userprofile: _user) => {
      console.log(userprofile.firstName);
    });
```

error: _user refer to value but is being used a type here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `_user` to `User`.

You return observable of `User` but in the method you assume data type az `_user`.

```
 this.userAccountService.getEmployees().subscribe((userprofile: User) => {
      console.log(userprofile.firstName);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `_user` as a type in `userprofile: _user`

Fix like this:

```
const _user: User = {
      userId: "30294
}
 this.userAccountService.getEmployees().subscribe((userprofile: User) => {
      console.log(userprofile.firstName);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete callback of subscribe method needs to be passed a variable with a type. But instead of a type, you passed a variable itself.

That's why you are getting the error.

```
_user refer to value but is being used a type here
```

So replace this:-

```
userprofile: _user
```

with this:-

```
userprofile: User
```

And you are good to go.